# HTML colspan not working on styled table with detached header

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a styled table that I´m building column resizing and other functions. Here is my code (available at [that Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ruyhedk/)):

```
<div class="ux-data-table">
  <div class="ux-data-table-inner">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="width: 20px; min-width: 20px; max-width: 20px;">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">
            <input type="checkbox" value="on">
          </span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip">
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="width: 300px; min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px;">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">Name</span>
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip"></div>
          </th>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="width: 300px; min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px;">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">Description</span>
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer"></span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip"></div>
          </th>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="width: 300px; min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px;">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">Property 1</span>
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer"></span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip"></div>
          </th>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="width: 300px; min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px;">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">Property 2</span>
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer"></span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip"></div>
          </th>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="width: 300px; min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px;">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">Property 3</span>
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer"></span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip"></div>
          </th>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="width: 300px; min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px;">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">Property 4</span>
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer"></span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip"></div>
          </th>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="width: 300px; min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px;">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">Property 5</span>
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer"></span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip"></div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="ux-data-table-nodata">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="8">No data found.</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ux-data-table {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 300px);
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
}

.ux-data-table-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.ux-data-table table {
  width: 100%;
}

.ux-data-table table,
.ux-data-table th,
.ux-data-table td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: blue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.ux-data-table thead {
  position: absolute;
}

.ux-data-table tbody {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.ux-data-table table thead tr th {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.ux-data-table table tr:hover td {
  background-color: #f0f0ff;
}

.ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.ux-data-table-th-title {
  cursor: n-resize;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.ux-data-table-th {
  position: relative;
}

.ux-data-table-th-grip {
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.ux-data-table-clear {
  clear: both;
}

.ux-data-table-checkbox-grayed {
  filter: invert(25%);
}

.ux-data-table-selected-cell td {
  background-color: #f0ffff;
}

.ux-data-table-nodata {
  position: initial;
  display: table-row-group;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The "grips" are going to be used for column resize together with javascript code and it is working fine (just to tell that the grips cannot be removed from HTML). In the same way, there are sort icons on columns that accepcts clicking for table sorting.

The header is detached, so that in a scroll movement the header shold remain on the top of div.

The table works fine when it has data on it.

Right now I want to show a message if the table has no data, something like "No data found". I need that message to be spreaded in my 8 columns.

I´ve used a colspan feature, but my problem is that the colspan is not showing in the full 8 columns of the table, but only at the first 2 columns.

I need a way to make the "No data found" line to show in all 8 columns. I cannot change the original CSS as the whole table is working (resizing columns, styling, detached header, etc.). Also the widths on columns are not fixed (they are fixed in this code, but they are dynamically build, so summing the widths will not solve the problem).

The class '`ux-data-table-nodata`' is not working, as somehow the width is being limited to the 2nd column.

How can I make the No Data Found column to extend horizontally to the 8 columns?

Comment: Are you sure you want 7 columns? You have 8 columns in the `<thead>` so you should either, add a `<td>` to the `<tr>` in `<tbody>`, change the `colspan` to 8, remove a `<th>` in`< thead>` or apply `rowspan=2` to either the first or last `th`

Comment: @zer00me: Sure, it is 8 columns!! I forgot the select column.... Edited and corrected...

Comment: You are using SASS? Please post CSS in compiled form.

Comment: Yes, I´m using SASS, but the post contains the resulting CSS (I just corrected one item that was referencing the SASS color).

Comment: What is `position:init`?

Comment: It is an error in code (mistype). Was supposed to be `position: initial` (corrected). Makes no effect or difference. Think can be removed.

Comment: I don't think there's an `initial` value for `position`, but there is the default value of `static`. Wait no there is `initial` my bad.

Comment: OK, I think i got it, see my answer, sir.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that you are detaching the table header from the html flow by setting its position to absolute.

Once you remove that and also remove display block from tbody, the table behaves as expected.

Here is an example:

HTML

```
<div class="ux-data-table">
  <div class="ux-data-table-inner">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="width: 20px;min-width: 20px;max-width: 20px;">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">
            <input type="checkbox" value="on">
          </span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip">
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="/* width: 300px; *//* min-width: 300px; *//* max-width: 300px; */">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">Name</span>
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip"></div>
          </th>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="/* width: 300px; *//* min-width: 300px; *//* max-width: 300px; */">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">Description</span>
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer"></span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip"></div>
          </th>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="/* width: 300px; *//* min-width: 300px; *//* max-width: 300px; */">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">Property 1</span>
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer"></span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip"></div>
          </th>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="/* width: 300px; *//* min-width: 300px; *//* max-width: 300px; */">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">Property 2</span>
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer"></span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip"></div>
          </th>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="/* width: 300px; *//* min-width: 300px; *//* max-width: 300px; */">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">Property 3</span>
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer"></span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip"></div>
          </th>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="/* width: 300px; *//* min-width: 300px; *//* max-width: 300px; */">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">Property 4</span>
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer"></span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip"></div>
          </th>
          <th class="ux-data-table-th" style="/* width: 300px; *//* min-width: 300px; *//* max-width: 300px; */">
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-title">Property 5</span>
            <span class="ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer"></span>
            <div class="ux-data-table-th-grip"></div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="ux-data-table-nodata">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="8" style="
    width: 400px;
">No data found.</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ux-data-table {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 300px);
  overflow: auto;
  /*float: left;*/
}


/* Prevents the header from overflowing the scrollbars */

.ux-data-table-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.ux-data-table table {
  width: 100%;
}

.ux-data-table table,
.ux-data-table th,
.ux-data-table td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  //    border-left: none;
  //    border-right: none;
  border-color: blue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.ux-data-table thead {
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.ux-data-table tbody {
  /*margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;*/
}

.ux-data-table table thead tr th {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.ux-data-table table tr:hover td {
  background-color: $ux-color-hover;
}

.ux-data-table-th-icon-spacer {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.ux-data-table-th-title {
  cursor: n-resize;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.ux-data-table-th {
  position: relative;
}

.ux-data-table-th-grip {
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.ux-data-table-clear {
  clear: both;
}

.ux-data-table-checkbox-grayed {
  filter: invert(25%);
}

.ux-data-table-selected-cell td {
  background-color: $ux-color-selected;
}

.ux-data-table-nodata {
  position: init;
  display: table-row-group;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And a fiddle demonstration

https://jsfiddle.net/jfeferman/bjyomm2s/

Assuming you set position absolute on thead to try to achieve a fixed header, you will need to do some css tricks as in the following example:

https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/sticky-header-and-footer-using-css/

Comment: As said I cannot remove the detaching due to other table features that are working (sort, col resize, fixed header on scroll, etc). I need a solution that preserves the existing classes... The trick you pointed out does not seen to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to have the colspan attribute work in a table that has a detached header. Given you also need features such as col resize you would need to resort to width calculation for your tbody cells. This can be done by calculating the width of columns when the table is attached to the DOM and then resizing the desired row. At some point you will need to refactor the css and implement javascript calculations to reach the desired functionality.